# Postgres Data Type for "2016-12-04T16:33:04.948+0000"?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, sqldatatypes

I have an unusual Date & Time format `2016-12-04T16:33:04.948+0000`

and I was wondering if...

1. Is this is actually unusual?
2. is there a preferred Data Type for the above?
3. Or should I just write something in python to split this into Date & Time?

Thanks!

Aaron

Comment: `timestamp` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Unusual? No, that format is an international standard: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Ah, thank you @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is no "unusual". It's the [international format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for a timestamp.

A `timestamp` data type is the natural choice for that in a database.

More details in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html